# Url rewrite that ignore some folders

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a centos server and i'd like to rewrite the url in this way:

---

**Example**

From:

```
/lang/"folder1"/"folder2"/"filename_n.php"
```

to:

```
/lang/filename_n.php
```

---

From:

```
/lang/"folder1"/"folder2"/"folder3"/"filename_n.php"
```

to:

```
/lang/filename_n.php
```

---

The folder "lang" is static while the other folders and file name change.

Very thank's :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^lang/(?:[^/]+/)+([^/]+)$ lang/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Very thank's for the immediate response!!

I'm sorry, but if I would change in this mode... - FROM: `/lang/"folder1"/"folder2"/"filename_n/"` - TO: `/lang/"filename_n.php"`

Comment: You can then use: `RewriteRule ^lang/(?:[^/]+/)+([^/.]+)/$ lang/$1.php [L]`